# How to build automatically on Github merge

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins but I haven't found an effective solution to this. I want Jenkins to automatically build my project from my master branch after I have made a merge to that branch from other branches. I'd like to find a solution without using a cron job. I tried using the build trigger where it says "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" but it doesn't seem to work. Are there other options?

Comment: You can look at: http://sanketdangi.com/post/62740311628/integrate-jenkins-github-trigger-build-process

Comment: You can look at: http://fourkitchens.com/blog/2011/09/20/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github